# Send Data in a DataForm of one excel to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code where BasedeDatos is a new sheet on a new excel (where my data will be displayed on). I want to transfer the data that is on every "TextBox" which are ID, Surname, Name, and so on to the new excel sheet. It works now!, but i don´t want the sheet to open every time i click on the button and transfer the data to the other sheet. How i can fix that?

```
Private Sub cmdAdd2_Click()
'dimention the variable
Dim Datos As Worksheet
Dim Addme As Range
'set the variable
Set Datos = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rescariz\Desktop\Plataforma\Datos.xlsx").Worksheets("Datos")
'error handler
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'set variable for the destination
Set Addme = Datos.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Me.TextBox7 = "" Or Me.TextBox8 = "" Or Me.TextBox9 = "" Or Me.ComboBox3 = "" Or Me.TextBox20 = "" Or Me.TextBox21 = "" _
Or Me.TextBox22 = "" Or Me.TextBox23 = "" Then
MsgBox "Hay celdas sin completar, por favor, llenar todos los datos"
Exit Sub
End If
'send the values to the base
With Datos
'add the unique reference ID then all other values
Addme.Value = Me.TextBox7
Addme.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.TextBox8
Addme.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.TextBox9
Addme.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.TextBox10
Addme.Offset(0, 4).Value = Me.TextBox11
Addme.Offset(0, 5).Value = Me.ComboBox3
Addme.Offset(0, 6).Value = Me.TextBox20
Addme.Offset(0, 7).Value = Me.TextBox21
Addme.Offset(0, 8).Value = Me.TextBox22
Addme.Offset(0, 9).Value = Me.TextBox23
End With
'sort the Registros by "Legajo"
Datos.Select
With Datos
.Range("A2:I1000").Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
End With
'communicate with the user
MsgBox "Se le han agregado los datos correctamente!"
'reset the form
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:
'if error occurs then show me exactly where the error occurs
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & _
" (" & Err.Description & ")en el procedimiento cmdAdd2_Click de la UserForm1"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Im trying to use the Workbook.Open method, but i can´t manage to make it work yet

Comment: I dont see anything in your code related to `.Open` - but you may want to be aware that `.Open` is a method of the `WorkBooks` (plural) object, not the `WorkBook` object.

Comment: @braX Im trying to follow this page: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open#example). But im a bit stuck. i set `Set BasedeDatos = Workbook.Open(BasedeDatos.xlsx).Worksheets("BasedeDatos")` but it gives me an error.

Comment: see how that page says `Workbooks` and not `Workbook`?

Comment: @braX i fixed the code but i don´t want every time to open the new sheet when i transfer that, how i can fix that? I put the new code in the description

Comment: once you have the variable `BasedeDatos` set, you just use that to reference the workbook each time.

Comment: I used `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True` to close after its send the data. I t works fine, maybe i would have to change afterwards so it does not match any other opened workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Me.TextBox8` makes sense only if your code works on the module of the sheet keeping the text box code;

Define the the sheet keeping the text boxes and use that like this:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, txtStr As String
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
 txtStr = sh.Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value
```

2. Better declare the workbook where you want to paste data and also specifically declare its sheet. Otherwise, VBA refers to the active workbook sheet. `BasedeDatos` as you defined it, is a sheet of the active workbook.

```
Dim w As Workbook, shB As Worksheet, Addme As Range
 Set w = Workbooks("BasedeDatos.xlsx")
 Set shB = w.Worksheets("BasedeDatos")
 Set Addme = shB.Cells(shB.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

Comment: I manage to make it work now, but i don´t want every time to open the new sheet when i transfer that, how i can fix that?

Comment: Try to understand what 'use here your sheet' means... I didn't know what sheet you usr and I use ActiveSheet only because of that. Please use Set sh = Workbooks("your workbook name").Worksheets("your sheet name").

Comment: I update the code in the description. I didn´t use your code, but i manage to make it work anyways. Yet, i need just to fix so it does not open the excel when i press to send the data. I fix it to open on the background, it is possible so it does not open?

Comment: @Santiago: This wan not "my code" able to solve your problem! It wanted to give you some hints  in order to solve the unappropriate approach. It is good you could solve it...